# isResourceAccount always null

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am fetching a list of users from the Microsoft Graph API and want to differentiate between "human" users on one side and equipment and rooms on the other. However the `isResourceAccount` is always null - which should be considered false judging by the [Microsoft Graph API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Has anyone encountered this issue - is it a known defect? Or am I misinterpreting the functionality of the `isResourceAccount` property?

Example call: 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,isResourceAccount`

Example response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,userPrincipalName,isResourceAccount)",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "Admin User",
            "userPrincipalName": "admin@testtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "isResourceAccount": null
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Printer",
            "userPrincipalName": "printer@testtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "isResourceAccount": null
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Test User",
            "userPrincipalName": "test@testtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "isResourceAccount": null
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Test room",
            "userPrincipalName": "testroom@testtenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "isResourceAccount": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: We are experiencing exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of November 2020, the `isResourceAccount` User property on the [Graph API documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) has this note for description:
Do not use - reserved for future use.

[image]

I guess this field could be used in an unspecified future, but not yet.